# You did not select a file to upload while uploading the multiple images

Tags: php

```
<?php
class AddNewsController extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('footer');
        $this->load->view('add-news-views');

    }

    public function add_news_proccess(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('news_title', 'News_Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('paragraphs[]', 'paragraphs', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tags[]', 'Tags', 'required');

        if (empty($_FILES['home_image']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('home_image', 'Document', 'required');
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = '1024';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024';
            $config['max_height'] = '1024'; 
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('home_image'))
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                print_r($error);
                // $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {

                $config = array();
                $config['upload_path'] = './para_imgs/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
                $config['max_size'] = '1024';
                $config['max_width'] = '1024';
                $config['max_height'] = '1024'; 

                $this->load->library('upload');

                $para_img_list = array();
                $files = $_FILES;
                print_r($_FILES['image_upload']["name"]);
                foreach($_FILES['image_upload']["tmp_name"] as $file => $fileArray){

                    $file_name=$_FILES["image_upload"]["name"][$file];
                    if($file_name != null){
                        echo "hii"."<br>";
                        $_FILES['image_upload']['name'] = $_FILES["image_upload"]["name"][$file];
                        $_FILES['image_upload']['type'] = $_FILES['image_upload']['type'][$file];
                        $_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name'][$file];
                        $_FILES['image_upload']['error'] = $_FILES['image_upload']['error'][$file];
                        $_FILES['image_upload']['size'] = $_FILES['image_upload']['size'][$file];    

                        $this->upload->initialize($config);
                        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image_upload'))
                        {
                            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                            print_r($error);
                            // $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                        }else{

                            $para_img_list[] = $_FILES['image_upload']['name'][$file];    
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "for default image";
                    // $this->load->model('Default_image');
                    // $default_img = $this->Default_image('default_img');
                    // print_r($default_img);
                    }



                }




                $news_data = array('news_title'=>$this->input->post('news_title'),
                                    'news_image'=>$_FILES['home_image']['name'],
                                    'posted_by'=>'shiva',
                                    'status'=>'INACTIVE');
                $paragraphs_list = $this->input->post('paragraphs[]');
                $paragraphs_img_list = $this->input->post($_FILES['image_upload']['name']);
                $tags_list = $this->input->post('tags[]');
                $this->load->model('AddNewsModel');
                $this->AddNewsModel->addnews($news_data, $para_img_list, $paragraphs_list, $tags_list);

            }
        }
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: please help me iam new to ask aquetions in stackoverflow  i dont know how to ask professionally please excuse me if any wrongs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You need to ask a question, not just post a bunch of code. Explain what the code should do, and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask